# Programmatically set dxComponentPrinter1Link1 ReportTitleText

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am struggling to programmatically set the report title in code. I could do it manually in the designer but that's not something I would like to do if I can do it in code.

The situation is this : I have 2 cx grid's. First one is showing the various departments while the other is showing all contacts linked to selected department in the first grid (afterscroll event)

I am printing the contents of the second grid, where the contacts are displayed. However, I would like the report title to be the name of the department in the first grid.

Something like this:

```
dxComponentPrinter1Link1.ReportTitleText :=Mytable.FieldByName('department').asString;
```

But I can't figure out where to write this code of mine (assuming it's right). Or any other way?

Comment: DevExpress provides an excellent support website in Q&A style just like stackoverflow. There is a very good chance that you will get a direct answer by their support staff if you ask your question there.

Comment: is dxComponentPrinter1Link1.PrinterPage.PageHeader what you're after?

Comment: actually its more like : dxComponentPrinter1Link1.ReportTitle.Text := ... But where do you put this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally :

```
procedure TForm5.dxComponentPrinter1BeforePreview(Sender: TObject;
  AReportLink: TBasedxReportLink);
begin
dxComponentPrinter1Link1.ReportTitle.Text := DataModule2.MyTable.FieldByName('department').asstring;
end;
```